# Consumer returns empty List instead of actual data

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am using the provider package for flutter.
https://pub.dev/packages/provider

On Appstart, I use the following provider:

```
late Future<List<Art>> art;
late Future<List<Music>> music;
late Future<List<Furniture>> furniture;
late Future<List<Clothing>> clothing;
late Future<List<Flower>> flowers;
late Future<List<Interieur>> interieur;
late Future<List<Collectible>> allCollectibles;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    art = getAllArts();
    music = getAllMusic();
    furniture = getAllFurniture();
    clothing = getAllClothing();
    flowers = getAllFlowers();
    interieur = getAllInterieur();

    allCollectibles = () async {
      return [
        ...await art,
        ...await music,
        ...await furniture,
        ...await clothing,
        ...await flowers,
        ...await interieur,
      ];
    }();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    timeDilation = 1;

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: settings,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }

        return FutureProvider<List<Collectible>>(
                    create: (context) => allCollectibles, initialData: [],
                  ),});
```

later on, I use this consumer to retreive it:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<List<Collectible>>(builder: (context, collectibles, child) {
      return sendCollectibleDataFull(collectibles),
    });
  }
```

The list in the Method `sendCollectibleDataFull` is sometimes there and sometimes not.
If it is empty on call, it will stay empty.

I have updated to nullsafety hence the `initialData: [],` got mandatory. Before that, I always got a list from this.

Can I tell my Consumer/Provider to await the data before I retreive it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @lellek and welcome.

Okay there are a couple of things I want to point out.

You're using the default `FutureProvider` constructor with a create callback but in fact you're providing a value that already exists.

```dart
        return FutureProvider<List<Collectible>>(
                    create: (context) => allCollectibles, initialData: [],
                  ),});
```

If you already have a value and you're not creating it with the Provider, you should use the [`.value`](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/FutureProvider/FutureProvider.value.html) constructor.

However, you could use the default constructor with the `create` callback and do all the work there instead of having this `StatefulWidget` doing some of the work (unless you just need these instances here as well).

This is not tested but it should look something like this:

```dart
FutureProvider<List<Collectible>>(
  create: (context) async {
    /// get collectibles in parallel
    final List<List<Collectible>> results = await Future.wait([
      getAllArts(), 
      getAllMusic(), 
      getAllFurniture(), 
      getAllClothing(), 
      getAllFlowers(), 
      getAllInterieur(),
    ]);

    /// flatten the results
    final allCollectables = [for (final collectibles in results) ...collectibles];

    return allCollectables;
  }, 
  initialData: [],
)
```

> Can I tell my Consumer/Provider to await the data before I retreive it?

No, the point is that the initial value, in this case `[]`, will be available from the provider and the tree will update when the future is resolved.